# Rails: Performance of checking to see if a set contains a value vs adding it multiple times

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, loops

I have a loop that will iterate tens of thousands of times, and a set that may have only 50 distinct values. Which of the following is more efficient to have as part of the loop?

```
if !myset.include?('value')
  myset.add('value')
```

or

```
myset.add('value')
```

Comment: what is the objective of the loop ?

Answer (score 2):

If it is more often that `myself` already has the values, then the whole execution in the first code would be just the `if` condition, and the second one which does `add` anyway would probably be slightly slower.

If it is more often that `myself` does not have the values, then in the first code, evaluation of the condition is extra and would be slower whereas the second one would be slightly faster.

Either way, I think the difference is so subtle that it can be absorbed within the error.

Answer (score 1):

If we randomize over a set of 50 distinct values:

```
require 'benchmark'

Benchmark.bm do |b|
  b.report do
    set = []
    100_000.times do
      i = rand(50)
      set.push(i)
    end
  end

  b.report do
    set = []
    100_000.times do
      i = rand(50)
      unless set.include?(i)
        set.push(i)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

the result I get is `0.04` against `0.2` with checking. So its 5 times faster if you don't perform checking in this case.

The larger is the set of randomized values the longer it is going to take (with checking).

You can try to perform similar benchmark with your code to see what tendencies you get. Run it with large numbers and multiple times to get cleaner results.

**Update:**

```
require 'set'
require 'benchmark'

Benchmark.bm do |b|
  b.report do
    set = Set.new
    100_000.times do
      i = rand(50)
      set.add(i)
    end
  end

  b.report do
    set = Set.new
    100_000.times do
      i = rand(50)
      unless set.include?(i)
        set.add(i)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Running with actual `Set` both examples appear to be slower and quite similar - around `0.48`.

Comment: That's with an array. With an actual set it's going to be very different

Answer (score 0):

If you use [Set](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html) you don't need write `if` just `myset.add('value')`, what about speed `set.add` is mostly the same as `array.push`